# Jquery click function not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display an alert box through a link and using jQuery but it seems that I didn't have done the things right.

My link :

```
<a class="details_link">Details</a>
```

My jQuery function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".details_link").click(function () {

            alert("test");
        });
    })
```

This code is not working... I've checked other answers on Stack but I think I have followed the instructions. And I'm including the jquery-1.9.1.js file.

Comment: Your code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/jEJBF/

Comment: Like http://jsfiddle.net/VW45D/ it seems to work, are you sure you're not including your anchor inside another div?

Comment: @steo That wouldn't matter, he's targeting the link directly.

Comment: Have you used this line: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />`

Comment: @izuriel I know, but if he's not clicking the right thing is not gonna work.

Comment: @steo That would happen regardless of how it's nested, but it's a link so it's underlined and has a hover effect (unless he's removed them).

Comment: where are you Traffy `:D`

Comment: I'm including the good script, my div is not into an other div and it still does not work. It pretty strange but thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

First check you have the correct jQuery Scripts loaded.

You are missing a few things.

The href attribute is missing from your anchor tag, although this is not what is causing the issue it is bad practice to not include it.

```
<a href="#"class="details_link">Details</a>
```

You are also missing a semi colon from your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".details_link").click(function () {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure you are properly refering the jquery library. Your code works for me. **[Check out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmwyA/)**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

You can go also verfiy if you jquery library is proper and ready for use by going to

> IE debugger >> script tag and in dropdown next to start debugging jquery library should appear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much guarantee it's not jqueries click function that isn't working properly, but something in you code.

1. Make sure you are including the jQuery library.
2. Make sure you have your function inside of `<script>` tags.
3. Check the web console to see if there are errors that need to be resolved.

Then,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('test1');
    $(".details_link").on('click',  function () {
        alert("test2");
    });
    console.log('test3');
});
console.log('test4');
```

See which of those `console.log` statements print.

Comment: You should use `console.log` when debugging prints over `alert` because `alert` is blocking and, depending on what you're doing, can cause the rest of the application to fail.